# Weird error and red screen when trying to build React Native project to device

Tags: ios, xcode, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to build my react-native project on to my iphone but keep getting the following error:

```
2015-11-01 20:50:19.134 [error][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] 'Error: Can\'t find variable: Symbol\n stack: \n  <unknown>  main.jsbundle:64380\n  require    main.jsbundle:254\n  <unknown>  main.jsbundle:64198\n  require    main.jsbundle:254\n  <unknown>  main.jsbundle:64125\n  require    main.jsbundle:254\n  <unknown>  main.jsbundle:64028\n  require    main.jsbundle:254\n  <unknown>  main.jsbundle:1409\n  require    main.jsbundle:254\n  <unknown>  main.jsbundle:1398\n  require    main.jsbundle:254\n  require    main.jsbundle:200\n  <unknown>  main.jsbundle:95010\n URL: file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/8E332C19-45CF-4874-AC61-7427C508ED16/Jobletics.app/main.jsbundle\n line: 64380\n message: Can\'t find variable: Symbol'
2015-11-01 20:50:19.238 [info][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] 'Running application "Jobletics" with appParams: {"rootTag":1,"initialProps":{}}. __DEV__ === false, development-level warning are OFF, performance optimizations are ON'
2015-11-01 20:50:19.241 [error][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] 'Error: Invariant Violation: Application Jobletics has not been registered. This is either due to a require() error during initialization or failure to call AppRegistry.registerComponent.\n stack: \n  runApplication  main.jsbundle:44346\n  __callFunction  main.jsbundle:5536\n  <unknown>       main.jsbundle:5472\n  guard           main.jsbundle:5425\n  <unknown>       main.jsbundle:5472\n  <unknown>       main.jsbundle:5469\n  perform         main.jsbundle:7017\n  batchedUpdates  main.jsbundle:16438\n  batchedUpdates  main.jsbundle:6320\n  <unknown>       main.jsbundle:5468\n  guard           main.jsbundle:5425\n  processBatch    main.jsbundle:5467\n URL: file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/8E332C19-45CF-4874-AC61-7427C508ED16/Jobletics.app/main.jsbundle\n line: 2012\n message: Invariant Violation: Application Jobletics has not been registered. This is either due to a require() error during initialization or failure to call AppRegistry.registerComponent.
```

With this screen[image]

I have done $ react-native bundle. Could it have something to do with permissions? Please help.

Comment: Silly question, but does it work on the Simulator? I'm guessing that the ES6 `Symbol()` keyword isn't being transpiled by Babel: https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/#symbols

Comment: Turned out it is sensitive to iOS version -- after I update to iOS 9, it worked. Sucks that its not ver agnostic.

Answer (score 2):

I know that React Native team is working on this issue, but if you're looking for a temporary fix in the meantime I suggest using this polypill.

https://github.com/medikoo/es6-symbol